# Decimalformat in exported xls file differs from JTable

Tags: java, excel, swing, jtable, export

I'm trying to Export Jtable Data into the Excel Sheet using HSSFWorkbook. I'm getting all the data from the JTable but the decimal format differs from the JTable. Please can anyone help me...

For example: 
JTable       -> 4,555
Exported xls -> 4,55479080958

Here the Command used for Taking content of the JTable:

```
try {
        for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
            fRow1 = workbookSheet.createRow((short) i);

            for (int j = 0; j < tableModel.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                HSSFCell cell = fRow1.createCell((short) j);
                cell.setCellValue(tableModel.getValueAt(i, j).toString());

            }

        }

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\file.xls");

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        hssfWorkbook.write(bos);
        bos.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            fRow1 = workbookSheet.createRow((short) i);

            for (int j = 0; j < tableModel.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                HSSFCell cell = fRow1.createCell((short) j);
                cell.setCellValue(tableModel.getValueAt(i, j).toString());

                System.out.println(tableModel.getColumnName(j));
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's the code for the JTable:

```
public class FileModel extends AbstractTableModel implements FilenameFilter {

List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();

String titles[] = new String[] { "File Name", "Pages", "Media Box Height", "Media Box Width", "Trim Box Height",
        "Trim Box Width", "Path" };
Class<?> types[] = new Class[] { String.class, Integer.class, Float.class, Float.class, Float.class, Float.class,
        String.class };

public FileModel() {
    this("C:\\");

}

public FileModel(String directory) {
    File inputFiles = new File(directory);
    setFileStats(inputFiles);
}

// Implement the methods of the TableModel interface Only getRowCount(), getColumnCount() and getValueAt() are
// required.
//

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return this.data.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return this.titles.length;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return this.titles[column];
}

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
    return this.types[column];
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    return this.data.get(row)[column];
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the Excel format?

Comment: oh man, thx. I really forget to set the format...

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188); a [short, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is always welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used DecimalFormat:

```
 DecimalFormat formatDecimal = new DecimalFormat("###.000");
```

and later on I add the Object to my AbstractTable using DecimalFormat:

```
this.data.add(new Object[] { file.getName(), formatDecimal.format(123.42345),file.getAbsolutePath() });
```

Comment: This works for a column of type `String`; alternatively, consider a [custom renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for a numeric type.